# Rename selfdefined function

Tags: zsh, function

Having a precmd() that does quite a lot, like checking for VCS information, I want to disable it when I'm navigating on slow mounted network drives.

I came up with the following with which I can say `slow` before changing to a slow drive and `fast` to change it back, I'm wondering if there is something easier?

```
precmd_slow() {
    not_much
}
precmd_fast() {
    precmd_slow
    somemore1
    somemore2
}

precmd() {
    precmd_fast
}

slow() {
    precmd() {
        precmd_slow
    }
}

fast() {
    precmd() {
        precmd_fast
    }
}
```

Comment: If you navigate the same slow drives a lot, a [`directory-specific zshrc`](http://michael-prokop.at/blog/2011/10/08/rocking-zsh-directory-specific-shell-profiles-screencast/) might help automate the process, although keybinding your function might just be as easy. Just a thought.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the `precmd` function, there is also an array called `precmd` that contains a list of functions to call at the same time. You can manipulate it yourself, but `zshcontrib` has a function `add-zsh-hook` to simplify matters.

```
# precmd_slow and precmd_fast defined as before

autoload add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook precmd precmd_fast

fast () {
    add-zsh-hook -d precmd precmd_slow
    add-zsh-hook precmd precmd_fast
}

slow () {
    add-zsh-hook -d precmd precmd_fast
    add-zsh-hook precmd precmd_slow
}
```